# Prove that $\left| \dfrac{an^k + f(n)}{bn^l+g(n)} \right|\to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Suppose $k,l \in \Bbb{N}$, $a,b \in \Bbb{R^*}$ (non-zero reals), and consider the functions $f:\Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{N}, g:\Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{N}$, such that $\dfrac{f(n)}{n^k} \to 0, \dfrac{g(n)}{n^l}\to0$.

Prove that if $k>l$, then $\left| \dfrac{an^k + f(n)}{bn^l+g(n)} \right|\to \infty$

---

I'm stucked at this problem. Please if possible also tell if my attempt is at least making sense so far.

My attempt:

Let $M > 0$

There are $N_1>0$ st. $n \ge N_1 \implies \left|\dfrac{f(n)}{n^k} \right|< M$ and $N_2>0$ st. $\left| \dfrac{g(n)}{n^l}\right|<M$. Let $N = \max\{M_1,M_2\}$

$M > \left|\dfrac{g(n)}{n^l}\right| \implies Mn^l > g(n) \implies Mn^l + bn^l > g(n) + bn^l \implies \dfrac{1}{bn^l + g(n)} > \dfrac {1}{Mn^l + bn^l} $

$k > l \implies n^k > n^l \implies an^k > an^l \implies an^k + f(n) > an^l + f(n)$. (I considered $a>0$ just to see if I got something)

Then, for all $n \ge N$, $\left| \dfrac{an^k + f(n)}{bn^l + g(n)} \right| \ge \dfrac{an^l + f(n)}{Mn^l + bn^l} = \dfrac{a}{M+b}+\dfrac{1}{M+b}\dfrac{f(n)}{n^l}$

And if I could guarantee $\dfrac{f(n)}{n^l} \to 0$ I would have done it, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easier approach:

AS $k-l>0$, we have that:
$$\left| \dfrac{an^k + f(n)}{bn^l+g(n)} \right| = \left| \dfrac{an^k + f(n)}{bn^l+g(n)} \right| \cdot \frac{1/n^k}{1/n^k} = \left|\frac{a+f(n)/n^k}{b/n^{k-l}+g(n)/n^{k}}\right| =$$
$$= \left|\frac{a+f(n)/n^k}{(b+g(n)/n^l)/n^{k-l}}\right| = n^{k-l}\left|\frac{a+f(n)/n^k}{b+g(n)/n^l}\right| \to +\infty \left|\frac{a+0}{b+0}\right|=+\infty$$